# Fetching youtube live chat with pytchat

Tags: python, youtube, livechat

```
import pytchat
chat = pytchat.create(video_id="uIx8l2xlYVY")
while chat.is_alive():
    for c in chat.get().sync_items():
        print(f"{c.datetime} [{c.author.name}]- {c.message}")
```

Im using this one [pytchat script](https://github.com/taizan-hokuto/pytchat) to fetch youtube live chat. Usually its working fine but sometimes i got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytchat.py", line 14, in <module>
    for c in chat.get().sync_items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sync_items'
```

After that its stop working and i need to restart it manually.

Any idea how could i solve this issue? Maybe some kind of auto restart if there is no better option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try-except block to catch the error and restart the script.

```
import pytchat
chat = pytchat.create(video_id="uIx8l2xlYVY")
while chat.is_alive():
    try:
        for c in chat.get().sync_items():
            print(f"{c.datetime} [{c.author.name}]- {c.message}")
    except AttributeError:
        print("Error occurred. Restarting...")
        chat = pytchat.create(video_id="uIx8l2xlYVY")
```

Comment: Okey, looks like it worked but now hes just stopping without any error. lol?